# How to detect the power button press in a System app in android

Tags: android, android-broadcast

I have a custom ROM of Android and want to launch my app if power button is press specific number of times. I will make my app a System app so that it will have system privilege. I know power button press broadcast is not possible for user apps but for system apps it should be possible, if anyone knows please help me.
For example: Three times press the power button call the SOS number.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way would probably be to put your code in `frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/GestureLauncherService.java`.

Take a look at the patch implementing double-tap to launch camera for reference. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/5941c98%5E%21/

Comment: Where the code for opening the desired activity will be placed in GestrureLauncherService.java